# Is \tl_use:N required, recommended or just optional?

Tags: expl3, latex3

In `source3.pdf` I read

> ```
> \tl_use:N ⟨tl var⟩
> ```
>
> Recovers the content of a ⟨tl var⟩ and places it directly in the input stream. An error will be raised if the variable does not exist or if it is invalid. Note that it is possible to use a ⟨tl var⟩ directly without an accessor function.

Suggesting that `\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl` is the same as just simply call `\l_tmpa_tl` and both works – as far as I can tell – without a difference. So I’m wondering if it is recommended to prefix with `\tl_use:N` or not? And is the a difference between these two variants?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All variable types in `expl3` have accessor functions. In the case of the `tl` type, this is not *required*: as you may know, a `tl` is a TeX macro used for storage (no parameters), and TeX itself allows macros to be used directly. (In contrast, some other `expl3` variable types are TeX registers and thus *require* an accessor.) The documented behaviour of `tl` variables is that they can be used without the accessor: this is particularly useful where lower-level expansion is needed, for example

```
\exp_after:wN \foo:w \l_some_tl \q_stop
```

The function `\tl_use:N` does provide a slightly more useful error message than simply using a `tl` name directly in the case where the `tl` is undefined:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \foo used!
```

but is otherwise little different to using the variable directly. There is a slight performance hit to using the accessor and in general the team have favoured direct use of variables. On the other hand, the accessor does make the meaning of the code clear and consistent with other types: this is why it exists.

As such, one is free to use or omit `\tl_use:N` in code which follows `expl3` 'good style'.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Makes sense to me and I have to think about wether I want to use it or not. Kind of a follow-up question: Is it okay to use `\l_tmpa_dim` without the accessor everywhere a length register is required (e.g. `\geometry{top=\l_tmpa_dim}`)?

Comment: @Tobi I tend to use it when you are putting things into the document (e.g., `\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { foo } \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { baz } \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl`) but when it's used in a place where you expect a “variable” then I tend not to use it (e.g., `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { foo } \use:c { tobi_ \l_tmpa_tl _command: }`).

Comment: @Manuel: Sounds reasonable :-)